# having trouble getting selected value from php dynamic selection option

Tags: php, html

I want to show options from my database for users to check, but having trouble getting user's choice.

So, I write two php files,

the first one doing things like: getting data from database, displaying in select option, then submit value by post to and the second php file.

And the second php file just display the recieved value.

Here's the first php file:

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="second.php">
<Select name=”select_value”>
<? 
//connect to server
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));
$query = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($con));
$result = $con->query($query);

//display result in select option
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<Option value=".$row['ENTRY_ID']."> ".$row['ENTRY_NAME']."</Option><br>";
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</Select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the second php file:

```
<? 
$option = isset($_POST['select_value']) ? $_POST['select_value'] : false;
   if($option) {
      echo $_POST['select_value'];
   } else {
     echo "not getting value of select option";
     exit; 
   }
?>
```

If this works fine, I should see the selected value by the second php file, but I keep recieving my echo "not getting value of select option".
There must be something wrong between select option and my recieving file.
Can someone help?

Comment: Questions asking to find an error in your code are not too welcomed here.

Comment: Show us the HTML code, generated by the 1-st php. And var_dump($_POST) in the 2-nd php before you use them. Print the values here.

Comment: cannot answer my own question, so I post here.

I think my 1-st php works fine, because after doing 1-st php, my html code looks like this:

    ...
    <Select name=”select_value”>
    <option value="1"> first</option>
    <option value="2"> second</option>
    <option value="3"> third</option>
    </Select>
    ...

And my 2-nd php, dumping var of $_POST is null string.
But, it should contain values from 1-st php.

Comment: Oh my god, I made a stupid mistake.

Comment: Thanks everyone, double quote works. Orz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this `double quotes`

```
<Select name="select_value">
```

instead of `<Select name=”select_value”>`